# Adding flag "-fno-implicit-templates" to CMake file

Tags: c++, templates, makefile, cmake

I made a program that uses auto for derivation of template types. This program is compiled in C++11 using Make file (it works as expected), but I need to join the program into a bigger program that uses CMake file.

I tried to use something like this in the top folder of the project's CMakeLists.txt .

```
SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-std=gnu++11")
SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -fno-implicit-templates ")
```

But running the CMake file sends all kinds of errors related precisely to auto and template type variables.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try to append your flag instead of overwriting the others in the first line `set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")`

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps something overrides CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS somewhere else. Try setting compile flags on a per-target basis, e.g. using [`target_compile_options`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/target_compile_options.html) (for CMake 3.x):

```
target_compile_options(your_target "-std=gnu++11" "-fno-implicit-templates")
```

or [`set_property`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/set_property.html?highlight=set_property) if you're using CMake 2.8.x:

```
set_property(TARGET your_target APPEND_STRING PROPERTY
             COMPILE_FLAGS " -std=gnu++11 -fno-implicit-templates")
```

Comment: I see this answer more suited to be a comment. Just my 2 cents though.